# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, posts

I am getting this error after loading my php page:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress2/wp-content/themes/annonciation/page-42.php
>   on line 77

I could understand that it means that I have opened a certain bracket or parenthasis somewhere, and didn't close it, but I can't for the love of god find it! Here is my code:

```
<?php get_header();?>
<div id="container">
<!-- Glossaire -->
<p class="titrep" style="padding-top:192px;">- Glossaire -</p>

<div id="alphabet">
  <ul>
    <?php
foreach(range('A','Z') as $i) {?>
 <li>
  <?php echo $i;?>
 </li> 

<?php

if($i=='Z')
      {
        break;
      }
    else{
    ?>
    <li>.</li>
    <?php }
  }

?>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="mots">
<?php //$test=new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'mots')); ?>

<?php //while ( $test -> have_posts() ) : $test -> the_post();?>

<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'mots',
    'lettres'  => 'alpha',
    'order'    => 'ASC'
    ); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : {
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

 //some code that is sure not making the error (i removed it and still getting the error)

 endwhile;
}?>

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

what could the problem be?

Comment: What code lies on `Line 77` ? And should `lettres` be `letters`  in your 2nd WP_Query argument?

Comment: line 77 is the end of my document, so nothing there, and no, it shouldn't be letters, that's how my taxonomy is called in wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to add to the two answers given on this matter. It is important to know that if you use

```
if($the_query->have_posts() ) :
```

you will need to close that with

```
endif;
```

otherwise you will also get the same parse error as described.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : {
```

Curly braces or colon/end syntax? Pick one.

Also, here's some [recommended reading](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference Doc for [Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in WordPress, from that if you want to use `:` then no need to use `{}`. you can use one of them at same time.